# Hiring a solicitor for uk visit visa

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, serial-refusals

As my visitor visa was refused twice, I decided to use a solicitor who is accredited by the society of law to assist me.

I asked him what he will do. He said he will review my refusals and prepare my application so that it meets the requirements and then he will apply on my behalf. He also added that I might get refusal again and in this situation he will go for juicidial review.

My question is: is it safe to let him apply on my behalf?

Shouldn't I see the application before he applies so that I can be sure he is not missing anything which may negatively affect me? Should I ask him to offer a legal representation letter?

As it's my first time to do such a thing, can anyone tell me how the process will go on? What are things that I should take care about?

The visa is very important for me because I am going to take an exam which will allow me to be a doctor in UK, so I want to proceed with extreme caution.

Comment: You're the one paying him; in my experience when you pay for such a service you should have the right to name certain terms. If you want to see the application he prepares to review, tell him.

Comment: If you were referred via the Law Society then it should be reasonably safe to engage the solicitor's services. This is the only method we recommend to find a solicitor to help with a UK visa application.

Comment: I would typically expect a reputable solicitor to give you a letter setting out what services he will provide and what the costs will be. You are completely within your rights to ask to see the application before he submits it and to have a printed copy of it. You have to sign it anyway, he can’t do that for you even if he is acting on your behalf.

Comment: Judicial review for a visitor visa is absolute nonsense. This is a scam.

Comment: The only action after visitor  visa refusal  is juicidal review..as it is not allowed for appealing or administrative review under the category i apply for

Comment: @ahmed90 I would sound a note of caution about optimism over a possible judicial review for a U.K. visitor visa decision. A Judicial Review is concerned with the legality of a decision, not whether the decision was necessarily the right or wrong one. The judge will consider whether the decision-maker acted legally, reasonably, and proportionally, rather than examine the merits of the decision. https://ayjsolicitors.com/blog/visitor-visa-to-uk-refused-challenge-decision-through-judicial-review/

Comment: Be aware that judicial reviews can be extremely expensive. Make sure you are fully aware of all costs involved. Also it highly depends on the reason why you were refused the first two times. If you were caught with something very bad, especially if it was not long ago, then your chances are slim and you may be wasting your money.

Comment: I havent been caught with anything illegal. My refusals is due to funds which is from  my father and i demonsterated this and applied again.the second time is that my employer didn't aprove my visit in the hr letter,, in fact he approves it and i can apply again with a new letter,, but i dont want to enter serial of refusals.

Comment: This is for a PLAB (I or II?) exam, isn't it? There are multiple questions on this site about your situation. Please take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

If you hire an adviser regulated by the Office of the Immigration Services Commissioner (OISC), then it should be reasonably safe to engage their services. Your adviser must give you a letter immediately after you hire them saying:

- what work they’re doing for you
- how much you’ll be charged
- how you’ll pay them

https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser/hiring-an-adviser

You have a right to see the submission. Tell the adviser that you want to do this before you engage their services and ask them to confirm their agreement to your request in writing. If they don’t agree or seem reluctant, find another adviser.

Comment: The OP asked about procedures and safeguards when hiring a solicitor. Solicitors are exempt from regulation by the OISC (see Section 1 of this OISC doc: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/how-to-become-a-regulated-immigration-adviser/how-to-become-a-regulated-immigration-adviser). Thus, an OISC advisor will not necessarily be a solicitor.